# error in jquery ajax request

Tags: jquery

please help me fixing the following code , it is always giving error

```
 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
     url: "http://herokory.herokuapp.com/autocomplete/jsonpCallback/a",
     dataType:"jsonp"
 }).error(alert('error'));
```

the url http://herokory.herokuapp.com/autocomplete/jsonpCallback/a supports jsonp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), you need to have a callback function set up to handle the response. In this case:

```
http://herokory.herokuapp.com/autocomplete/jsonpCallback/a
```

you're specifying `jsonpCallback` as the name of the function in the URL. So, you need to have a function with that name, **visible in the global scope**, before you make the JSONP request:

```
function jsonpCallback(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
    url: "http://herokory.herokuapp.com/autocomplete/jsonpCallback/a",
    dataType:"jsonp"
}).error(alert('error'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The key that you pass to set the method to jsonp is `dataType` not `datatype`. Object keys are case sensitive

Additionally, on failure, jquery will send XHR, textStatus, and errorThrown. Why not take a look at those?:

```
...
.done(function (XHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(XHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
});
```

You need to define jsonpCallback outside of your ajax call:

```
function jsonpCallback(data) {
    // do stuff with data
    console.log(data)
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific on the terms of what error is being thrown. Additionally, this endpoint is not loading at all for me.

Comment: the error is jsonpCallback is not defined.where to define it ?

Comment: You need to define a function to be used as a callback, outside of your ajax call, see the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Use reponseText to get more details on the error.  Are you on the same domain?

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "http://herokory.herokuapp.com/autocomplete/jsonpCallback/a",
 datatype:"jsonp"
 }).responseText
```